# asp.net mvc: SQLDateTimeOverflow problem with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to update an object, and getting:

```
SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
```

There are two fields in the object that are DateTime objects, and they're set with:

```
  obj.created_date = DateTime.Now;
  obj.modified_date = DateTime.Now;
```

Except that everything looks reasonable when I view the object:

```
>? obj.created_date
{1/13/2010 4:02:47 PM}
    Date: {1/13/2010 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 13
    DayOfWeek: Wednesday
    DayOfYear: 13
    Hour: 16
    Kind: Unspecified
    Millisecond: 817
    Minute: 2
    Month: 1
    Second: 47
    Ticks: 633989953678170000
    TimeOfDay: {16:02:47.8170000}
    Year: 2010
>? obj.modified_date
{1/19/2010 12:20:50 PM}
    Date: {1/19/2010 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 19
    DayOfWeek: Tuesday
    DayOfYear: 19
    Hour: 12
    Kind: Local
    Millisecond: 333
    Minute: 20
    Month: 1
    Second: 50
    Ticks: 633995004503331818
    TimeOfDay: {12:20:50.3331818}
    Year: 2010
```

Any idea what's going on?  Even reading the fields from the database, then trying to save them back without changes, causes the error.  Other classes have no problems, and I can't see any differences that would account for this error.

I've added

```
    <globalization culture="en-US" />
```

to my web.config, with no changes.

These problems are on my local dev

Comment: could you post some code of exactly what you are doing when you access and save the objects please?

Comment: just guessing - is there yet another DateTime property somewhere, that might not be initialized (and thus is set to 0/0/0001 ?). The two you're showing are okay, those certainly don't cause any trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's what was happening.  marc_s had the right idea.

There's was binder handling the updates:

```
  TryUpdateModel(editItem, new string[] { "LookupTable", "TextField1", "TextField2" });
```

I removed the "LookupTable" from the call to TryUpdateModel, and instead handle the value in the binder with:

```
  var fkid = Convert.ToInt32(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["LookupTable.ID"]);
  EntityKey ek = new EntityKey("entities.LookupTable", "ID", fkid);
  obj.LookupTableReference.EntityKey = ek;
```

Apparently, the EF was trying to update the LookupTable value for some reason.